# Highcharts 3D Pie color rendering

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, 3d, highcharts

I facing a strange problem while generating a 3D-Pie chart using highcharts. The colors on different slices are not loading initially and are displaying only after mouse hover.

Code snippet:

```
module.pieChart = function (divid, title, subTitle, seriesData) {
 //seriesData is in form of json
        window[divid] = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: divid,
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: title
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: subTitle
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            }, legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + ' %';
                        }
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: title,
                data: seriesData
            }]
        }, NodataMessage);
    };
```

If anyone have any suggestions or solution to it.?

---

**EDIT**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8k8)**

Comment: please, create a jsfiddle example. We cant find the problem, if we dont see the example with your data.

Comment: probably, your data is not expected structure. [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie/) is working example...

Comment: sorry i am unable to generate fiddle for it.as data is from server.Its not related to data..pie chart is generating..but the colors on different slices are showing after hovering

Comment: get data from your browser console, and create jsfiddle example. In this form you wont get any answer, you are using standart options, and you should not get any error, so there is one problem:DATA.

Comment: ok..let me log my data and use it.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi problem is same as this http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8k8/

Comment: But your example doesnt work, can you replicate it as live demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its about `Highcharts.getOptions().colors`. This function generate 10 colors, and after tenth, colors list is null. And you try to push color like this:

```
// there is no color for i > 9
color:data[i].color;
```

`Highcharts.getOptions().colors` output is : `["#7cb5ec", "#434348", "#90ed7d", "#f7a35c", "#8085e9", "#f15c80", "#e4d354", "#8085e8", "#8d4653", "#91e8e1"]`

So, you should remove it from your options, or manually define it.

and working example:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alirizaadiyahsi/JKK89/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as @AliRıza Adıyahşi said - length of colors array. Simple solution is to take width of colors array, then instead of `colors[i]` use `colors[i % colors.length]`. See live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8k8/4/

Or just don't set colors, let Highcharts do that for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8k8/5/